# Prefix lines of stdin with zero-padded index in bash

Tags: bash

I know that `cat -n` can do

```sh
$ ls | cat -n
     1  file_1
     2  file_10
     3  file_2
     4  file_3
     5  file_4
     6  file_5
     7  file_6
     8  file_7
     9  file_8
    10  file_9
```

I know you can get the number of lines in a pipeline (i.e., `ls | cat -n | tee >(wc -l) | cat`) -- so the following should theoretically be possible.

Is there a simple way to do the same thing but with a zero-padded index?

```sh
$ ls | ?
01  file_1
02  file_10
03  file_2
04  file_3
05  file_4
06  file_5
07  file_6
08  file_7
09  file_8
10  file_9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `cat -n` with `awk`:

```
# ls | awk '{ printf "%03d %s\n", NR, $0 }'
```

Change `03` to the number of leading zeros you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse output of `ls` as it may contain whitespaces and glob characters.

You may use this script:

```
i=
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    printf '%02d\t%s\n' $((++i)) "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Remove option `-type f` if you want to list non-files also.

Answer (score -1):

The output of `ls` is not intended to be parsed for filenames. It is better to use a pattern matching expression (glob) or the `find` command for this purpose. The script below works for all filenames even if they contain white spaces (even the new-line character!) in them. It also equalizes the width of zero-padded line numbers since we know in advance the number of files to be listed in this approach.

```
files=(*)
nfiles=${#files[*]}
numwidth=${#nfiles}

for ((i = 0; i < nfiles; ++i)); do
    printf "%0${numwidth}d %s\n" $((i + 1)) "${files[i]}"
done
```